# What are the differences in the "app" parameter of a Procfile? (I'm using a gunicorn server)

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I'm working with Heroku in deploying a web app with a `gunicorn` server. My `Procfile` contains the following:
`web: gunicorn app:server`

I'm a bit lost as to what the `app` parameter corresponds to. This is related to a number of errors I keep receiving about `gunicorn` not being able to load the server. *I've attached my heroku logs report to demonstrate.*

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:server`
app[web.1]: [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
app[web.1]: [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:39834 (4)
app[web.1]: [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
app[web.1]: [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
app[web.1]: [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'server' in 'app'.
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use this if you don't know what it does? It would refer to the "server" object inside app.py; do you actually have an app.py? Does it contain a "server" object? That's not what you would normally call it. Show your app.py.

Comment: Thanks for the relevant Q's @DanielRoseman – here's where I'm sourcing from: https://dash.plot.ly/deployment

Comment: Not the best way of going about creating a program, I know. Thank you for being supportive and a resource.

Comment: Got it! *Note that app refers to the filename app.py. server refers to the variable server inside that file).*